# Using @AutoValue with nested classes gives a "cannot find symbol" error

Tags: java, auto-value

When trying to use [@AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value) with nested classes:

```
public class Nested {
  @AutoValue
  public static abstract class Example {
    public static Example create(String name, int integer) {
      return new AutoValue_Example(name, integer);
    }
    public abstract String name();
    public abstract int integer();
  }
}
```

I get a compiler error `cannot find symbol` for `AutoValue_Example`. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is the `AutoValue` type on the classpath at compilation time.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When your class is nested like this, the generated AutoValue class would be named `AutoValue_Nested_Example`.  As stated in the [docs](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value#nesting):

> Nesting
>
> For a nested abstract value type called Foo.Bar.Qux, the generated implementation class is named AutoValue_Foo_Bar_Qux.

Comment: Wouldn't the `Example` class also need to be `static`? (BTW, the `create` method also lacks the `static` keyword)

Comment: Yes, generally speaking.

Comment: FYI: I just edited the question to add the missing `static` keywords.

Answer (score 0):

The inner class (in case it is static) is generated in a separated source file named 'AutoValue_outerClass_innerClass'